# timezone used by google maps api while making use of departure time

Tags: google-maps, timezone

What is the time Zone used by the Google maps API while looking for a Transit or driving Information from a specific Location within a specific time Zone.

I make the following request
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.847247,-10.381659&destination=51.644174,7.23135&departure_time=1473423393

The origin is in Ireland, the destination in Germany, so we are in 2 different time zones.

The Server making the request is in GMT+0200.

Does it means the departure time and the arrival time are given back by the API are both in GMT+0200?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The arrival time is calculated from the  the elapsed time since the departure. So I assume it will be in the same time zone.
Have a look on [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/w36fpaNRvcI) forum.

Answer (score 0):

as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters) states, the departure time is expressed as *an integer in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC*, i.e., it is standard UNIX timestamp